# Differential equation with modulus

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with 
$$y-xy'=(ln|x|+1)y^2 $$
because I do not know how to deal with the absolute value.

I divide $\frac{y - xy'}{y^2}=ln|x| +1$, then substitute $t' = (\frac{x}{y})'$ 
get $$\frac{dt}{dx}=ln|x|dx +dx$$
and now I am stuck. What do I do further? Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a tip for naming the question: use the word "modulus" or "absolute value", since "module" means something entirely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x>0$, then you drop the absolute value and integrate to get $t=x\ln x$.
If $x<0$, then you replace the absolute value with a negative sign and integrate to get $t=x\ln(-x)$. In either case, $t=x\ln\vert x\vert$.